# How to access these keys and values in my json file with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I'm having trouble accessing keys and values in my json file. I've tried a bunch of things but my focus is shot this week and I'm stuck.

**Here's my transport.json file..**

```
{"transportation":[
    {"Springfield":[{
        "bus":[{
            "start": 6,
            "end": 24,
            "stops":["oak street", "main street"]
        }],
        "taxi":[{
            "start": 25,
            "end": 25,
            "stops":["all"]
        }]
    }]},
    {"Pleasantville":[{
        "bus":[{
            "start": 6,
            "end": 22,
            "stops":["centre street", "river street"]
        }],
        "taxi":[{
            "start": 25,
            "end": 25,
            "stops":["all"]
        }],
        "train":[{
            "start": 6,
            "end": 23,
            "stops":["uptown", "downtown"]
        }]
    }]}
]}
```

**The two things I'm trying to do are..**

1. I want to be able to alert the bus `start` value in users current area.
2. I want to loop through the bus `stops` to compare to users current stop.

**Here's my js code..**

```
var currentArea = 'Pleasantville'; // this variable changes
var currentStop = 'uptown'; // this variable changes
$.getJSON("transport.json", function(jsontransportation) {
    $(jsontransportation.transportation).each(function(dataaaa) {
        var areaName = Object.keys(this);
        if (areaName == currentArea) { // this works to find correct area in json
            $(this.bus).each(function(key, value) { // i can't get this loop to work
                alert(this.start); // alerts nothing, no errors
                $(this.stops).each(function(key) { // now im trying to loop through keys in 'stops'
                    if (this.key === currentStop) { // to compare stop to current area
                        alert('the bus stops here at ' + currentStop); // and alert if there is a stop here
                    } else {
                        alert('the bus does not stop here at ' + currentStop); // else alert no stop here
                    }
                })
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post what output you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @AliRasheed For 1. I just want to alert the value for now. I'll be saving it as a variable for some calculations in the final script. For 2. I need to check if the stop exists for the users current location (bus/train/transit stop). And a bunch of other things, this is just a stripped down version of the json and js files.

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen have a look at my answer. I guess you intend to alert the message only once rather that alert on each element on the stops array.

Comment: @AKA Thanks man, I'm just working through your answer now. I appreciate your fix, I realized I made that error after trying out the earlier answers. I'll try and decide what's best before I crash tonight, or tomorrow evening.

Comment: Sure @HastigZusammenstellen . hope to get positive feedback from you and at least a up vote for the work.

Comment: @AKA Ohh for sure and I appreciate the time you've taken to answer but I take it very serious. As soon as I get through each answer and am certain they work I do the upvoting. :)

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen yes that is really a positive thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is exactly what you need. I have also changed the code so that the alert is displayed only once.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var currentArea = 'Pleasantville'; // this variable changes
   var currentStop = 'uptown'; // this variable changes
  $.getJSON("transport.json", function(jsontransportation) {
      $(jsontransportation.transportation).each(function(dataaaa) {
          var areaName = Object.keys(this);
          if (areaName == currentArea) { 
             var selectedArea = this[currentArea];
             var bus = selectedArea[0].bus;
             var stops;
             $(bus).each(function(keyBus, valueBus) { 
               alert(this.start); 
               stops = false;
               $(this.stops).each(function(key, valueStops) { 
                      if (valueStops === currentStop) { 
                          stops = true;
                      } 
                  })
             });
             if(stops){
                alert('the bus stops here at ' + currentStop); 
             }else{
                alert('the bus does not stop here at ' + currentStop); // else alert no stop here
             }


          }
      });
  });
});
```

For work around here is the link to [PLUNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/RdiQ6STgYV9rLSGABBOD?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks again AKA. Your answer addressed what I asked for and also saw through the question to answer what I would have needed next. (the unnecessary alerts at each iteration)

Answer (score 1):

you are using wrong keys at various places, actually to check if bus stops at user's current stop, you don't need to loop through all stops and compare instead you can use indexOf(), following code should work:

```
var currentArea = 'Pleasantville'; // this variable changes
var currentStop = 'uptown'; // this variable changes
$.getJSON("transport.json", function(jsontransportation) {
    $(jsontransportation.transportation).each(function(dataaaa) {
        var areaName = Object.keys(this)[0];
        if (areaName == currentArea) { // this works to find correct area in json
        var selectedCityObject = this[areaName][0]
            $(selectedCityObject.bus).each(function(key, value) { // i can't get this loop to work
                alert(value.start); // alerts nothing, no errors
                if (value.stops.indexOf(currentStop) >= 0) { // to compare stop to current area
                        alert('the bus stops here at ' + currentStop); // and alert if there is a stop here
                    } else {
                        alert('the bus does not stop here at ' + currentStop); // else alert no stop here
                    }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Dij, I got your code working right away. I will have to read up more on indexOf(), I appreciate your mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var currentArea = 'Pleasantville'; // this variable changes
var currentStop = 'uptown'; // this variable changes
$.getJSON("transport.json", function(jsontransportation) {
    $(jsontransportation.transportation).each(function(index, area) {
        var areaName = Object.keys(this)[0];
        if (areaName == currentArea) { 
        vehicles = this[areaName][0];
            $(vehicles.bus).each(function(key, value) { 
                alert(value.start);
                $(value.stops).each(function(index, stopName) {
                    if (stopName === currentStop) { 
                        alert('the bus stops here at ' + currentStop); 
                    } else {
                        alert('the bus does not stop here at ' + currentStop);
                    }
                })
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Victor. I couldn't get this to work as is but it's probably an error on my end in changing the code to fit my script. The only bug in your answer that I can see so far is `vehicles =` should be `var vehicles =`.

Comment: This works fine, it was an error on my part. Thanks again Victor.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `serviceType` to get your data chunk. (Sorry, No jquery)

```js
var $data = {
  "transportation": [{
      "Springfield": [{
        "bus": [{
          "start": 6,
          "end": 24,
          "stops": ["oak street", "main street"]
        }],
        "taxi": [{
          "start": 25,
          "end": 25,
          "stops": ["all"]
        }]
      }]
    },
    {
      "Pleasantville": [{
        "bus": [{
          "start": 6,
          "end": 22,
          "stops": ["centre street", "river street"]
        }],
        "taxi": [{
          "start": 25,
          "end": 25,
          "stops": ["all"]
        }],
        "train": [{
          "start": 6,
          "end": 23,
          "stops": ["uptown", "downtown"]
        }]
      }]
    }
  ]
};

var search = function(currentArea, currentStop, serviceType, callback) {
  var found = false;
  $data.transportation.forEach(function(area) {
    var $transport = area[currentArea];
    if ($transport) {
      $transport.forEach(function($types) {
        $service = $types[serviceType];
        if ($service) {
          $service.forEach(function($details) {
            if ($details.stops.indexOf(currentStop) > -1) {
              found = $details;
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    callback(found, currentArea, currentStop, serviceType);
  }, 0);
};

function response(data, currentArea, currentStop, serviceType) {
  if (data === false) {
    alert("The " + serviceType + " doesn't stop at " + currentStop + " for " + currentArea);
  } else {
    alert(serviceType + " starts at " + data.start + " at " + currentStop + ", " + currentArea);
  }
}

var currentArea = 'Pleasantville';
var currentStop = 'uptown';

search(currentArea, currentStop, 'bus', response);
search(currentArea, currentStop, 'train', response);
search(currentArea, 'river street', 'bus', response);
search('Springfield', 'oak street', 'bus', response);
```

Comment: Why are you using setTimeout?

Comment: The solution is to "pause" the JavaScript execution to let the rendering threads catch up. And this is the effect that setTimeout() with a timeout of 0 does.

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful

Comment: Hi Priya, thanks for taking your time to help me but I couldn't see in your code where it alerted the 'start' value.

Comment: `console.log(found)` is nothing but a js printing statement like `alert`. You can do an alert too for the found variable. if your service type is train `alert(JSON.stringify(found))` will give you `{"start": 6, "end": 23, "stops": ["uptown", "downtown"]}` else `false`. Console shows data in developer toolbar

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen now you can check alerting the data.

Comment: @Priya What I meant was it's getting/alerting/logging the entire bus object, not alerting the single 'start' value which was all I needed for the first part of my problem.

Comment: @Priya Actually, it's currently alerting the 'train' object, not 'bus'.

Comment: Give any search you want. it will show you what you want and where.

Comment: @Priya read the question properly before you come up with anything, The OP seeks to have a easy answer that is straight forward for them to understand.